# How to test sql queries in magento?

Tags: mysql, sql, magento, testing, optimization

We have been facing sql query issues in Magento. Some of the customers complain that the queries used in Mogento extensions are not  in staandard. How shall I test whether the developers wrote queries in magento standard?

Comment: you need to check coding whether they are using proper resource model for querying to database

Answer (score 0):

Magento is a database resource oriented application.
You should check whether your developers are following standard api models to access db resources or not.
Secondly  use index table data more frequently to read command rather than making EAV resource query.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code it is hard to say exactly what they are referring to.

Take a look @ [Custom Module with Custom Database Table](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/5_-_modules_and_development/0_-_module_development_in_magento/custom_module_with_custom_database_table)

If in your code, they are things like

```
$resource   = Mage::getSingleton('core/resource');
$conn       = $resource->getConnection('core_read');
$results    = $conn->query('SELECT * FROM tblName');
```

Should be change to some thing like

```
$results  = Mage::getModel('module/model_name')->getCollection();
```